# Cypress component test - test fails when services are imported using an index.ts file and export

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, cypress

**Tech stack:** Angular v15 and Cypress v12.

**My example component that I'm testing:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { UserHttp } from '../../services';

@Component({
  selector: 'example-view',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
})
export class ExampleComponent {
  constructor(
    private userHttp: UserHttp,
  ) { }
}
```

**My example component test**

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { ExampleComponent } from './example.component';
import { UserHttp } from '../../services';

describe('Example component', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.mount(ExampleComponent, {
      providers: [UserHttp],
      imports: [HttpClientModule]
    });
  });

  it('should display default title', () => {
    cy.get('h2').should('exist');
  });
});
```

**My UserHttp service that I'm injecting:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class UserHttp {

  test(): Observable<any> {
    return of({});
  }
}
```

**Current status:**

The above test will fail if I leave the import as: **import { Http } from '..';**
But if I change it to this it works: **import { Http } from './http';**

The reason I have it as import { Http } from '..' is because I use an index file to export all the services like this:

```
// index.ts: services:
import { UserHttp } from './http/user.http';
import { StorageService } from './storage.service';

export * from './http/user.http';
export * from './storage.service';

export const SERVICES = [
  StorageService,
  UserHttp,
];
```

**My StorageService:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class StorageService {
  baseKey: string = environment.baseStorageKey;

  constructor() {}

  setLocalStorage(key: string, value: any): void {
    this.removeLocalStorage(key);
    localStorage.setItem(`${this.baseKey}${key}`, JSON.stringify(value));
  }

  getLocalStorage(key: string): any {
    const item = localStorage.getItem(`${this.baseKey}${key}`);
    return item !== null ? JSON.parse(item) : '';
  }

  removeLocalStorage(key: string): void {
    localStorage.removeItem(`${this.baseKey}${key}`);
  }

  removeBatchLocalStorage(keys: string[]): void {
    keys.forEach((key: string) => {
      localStorage.removeItem(`${this.baseKey}${key}`);
    });
  }
}
```

**This is my cypress config:**

```
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
  },
  chromeWebSecurity: false,
  screenshotsFolder: "cypress/snapshots",
  trashAssetsBeforeRuns: true,
  viewportWidth: 1400,
  viewportHeight: 1200,
  video: false,
  env: {
    local: "http://localhost:4200/",
    staging: "https://hidden.co.uk/",
    user: {
      email: "hidden",
      password: "hidden",
    },
  },
  component: {
    devServer: {
      framework: "angular",
      bundler: "webpack",
    },
    specPattern: "**/*.cy.ts",
  },
});
```

Is there anyway to set index.ts file approach to work in the tsconfig or cypress config?

**Current Error I get:**

```
     TypeError
The following error originated from your test code, not from Cypress.

  > Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'StorageService')

When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your test code it will automatically fail the current test.

Cypress could not associate this error to any specific test.

We dynamically generated a new test to display this failure.
```

**My TS Config file:**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": false,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "es2020",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["src/app/*"],
      "@services/*": ["src/app/services/*"]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": false,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": false,
    "strictTemplates": false
  }
}
```

**My http.ts server that is extended by the userHttp service:**

```
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export abstract class Http {
  protected baseUrl = environment.baseUrl;
  protected headers: HttpHeaders;

  constructor(public httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  protected get<T>(path: string, options: any = {}, noBaseUrl = false): Observable<T> {
    const url: string = this.createUrlString(path, noBaseUrl);
    const params: HttpParams = this.getHttpParams(options.queryString);
    return this.httpClient.get<T>(url, { params });
  }

  protected post<T>(path: string, data = {}, noBaseUrl = false): Observable<T> {
    const url: string = this.createUrlString(path, noBaseUrl);
    const options = { headers: this.headers };
    return this.httpClient.post<T>(url, { ...data, lang: 'uk' }, options);
  }

  protected createUrlString(resourcePath: string, noBaseUrl: boolean): string {
    return noBaseUrl ? `${resourcePath}` : `${this.baseUrl}${resourcePath}`;
  }

  protected getHttpParams(params: any): HttpParams {
    let httpParams: HttpParams = new HttpParams();

    if (params) {
      for (const prop in params) {
        if (params.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
          const parameterValue: string = params[prop].toString();
          httpParams = httpParams.append(prop, parameterValue);
        }
      }
    }
    return httpParams;
  }
}
```

**Gui error message**

[image]

Comment: why not import it as `import { Http } from './index'` ?

Comment: Thanks for getting in touch, I tried import { Http } from '../index'; instead of import { Http } from '..' and I had the same issue.

Comment: @Andres2142 any other ideas I can try?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the issue is with the typescript config settings.

I found this solution by making a new angular version 15 app with just cypress and it worked.

So I then compared the two tsconfig.json files.

This is the working tsconfig.json file that solved this issue:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "allowJs": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": false,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": false,
    "strictTemplates": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If I've reproduced the error correctly (it seems so because the change to the import you mentioned fixes it), then the error is

> ReferenceError
> The following error originated from your test code, not from Cypress.
>
> > Cannot access 'UserHttp' before initialization

You can fix it in the component by importing `UserHttp` via the services index rather than directly from it's implementation.

**example component**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
// import { UserHttp } from '../../services/http/user.http';
import { UserHttp } from '../../services';

@Component({
  selector: 'example-view',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
})
export class ExampleComponent {
  constructor(
    private userHttp: UserHttp,
  ) { }
}
```

[image]

The reason, I think, is that `UserHttp` is dependent on `services/index` but this index is not directly referenced by the test, and therefore does not get complied.

The error message does seem confusing, it should be complaining about `Http.ts` rather than `UserHttp.ts`.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the error I get above for your solution. I get an ivy error

Comment: My error occurs because I'm importing using this: import { UserHttp } from '../../services' in all the files. The reason I do this is because I use an index.ts file in my services folder. And in the index.ts file I import and export like so: export * from './http/http';
export * from './http/user.http';

Comment: I've just added my tsconfig above because the ivy error mentions this: is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.

Comment: I was originally running Angular 14 - just managed to upgrade to Angular 15.2.0 but it's still passing the test after upgrade. I also pasted your tsconfig.json, and it's still working.

Comment: The only other differences are `ResponseModel` (changed to `any` type) and `Http.ts` is as simple as needed to get things working. Maybe the base class of `Http` is the problem, as I don't know what that is.

Comment: This is the script I run: "cy:gui": "cypress open -e \"TAGS=not @ignore\"",

npm run cy:gui

Comment: I've also just added my Http abstract service that my service implements

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253969/discussion-between-angularm-and-suchanignorantthingtodo-ukr).

Comment: I've added the error message above and the latest code I have